# Gtk::Actionable Gtk::RadioToolButton?

Tags: c++, radio-button, gtk3, gtkmm

I'm using gtkmm to build a UI.  The task I'm trying to accomplish is constructing a radio button from an action that is already part of a menu and a toolbar.  I'd like the new button to proxy for the existing action.

One likely candidate is Gtk::Action::create_tool_item().  Its documentation states:

> Deprecated: 3.10: Use a Gtk::ToolItem and associate it with a Action using Gtk::Actionable::set_action_name() instead

So, I'd expect that ToolItem and by inheritance RadioToolButton would implment this interface.  In gtkmm-3.12 it does not and the stable documentation reflects this as well.

However, the C library gtk-3.0 RadioToolButton does implement this interface.  So, my question is this.

**Should gtkmm Gtk::RadioToolButton implement Gtk::Actionable?  Is the absence of this int erface an oversight, or is there another way that the features of Actionable are supported?**

There is a function, set_related_action() which associates the correct icon for the radio button.  It doesn't seem to put the button into the group and it is also deprecated.

Comment: I found a way forward, but it's just plain confusing.  Gtkmm's UI manager wraps the Gtk+ UI manager.  The Gtk+ UI manager (v3.12) source is in a directory gtk/deprecated.  Nothing in the documentation seems to explain what replaces it and the examples hold up the UI manager as the pinnacle of convenience...which it does seem to be.  In the implementation of UI manager, tool items for toolbars are created with the create_tool_item() call which is deprecated in the documentation.  So, I suppose that my mistake was assuming that the deprecated interface has a successor.  Perhaps it doesn't, yet.

Comment: If you build your ui with GtkBuilder then you can specify the action name for the radio buttons in the builder XML. I think GtkBuilder is a more capable replacement for GtkUIManager

Comment: I believe you are correct in that GTK+ is moving from UI manager to GtkBuilder.  I posted this question to the GTK+ list and was told that these interfaces are in flux and that GTKMM will catch-up to GTK+ in the next major release.

Comment: @PhillipWood, with Gtk::Builder, how do I specify the target parameter for the activated RadioToolButton?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. This is certainly not documented as clearly as it could be. But I found a thread on the mailing list (perhaps also yours!) from a few months after this one, which answers both of your main questions, and I think it's worth posting for future people following the same path.

To summarise:

> Is the absence of this int erface an oversight

Of course not: it was a deliberate decision, for an extremely important reason.

> or is there another way that the features of Actionable are supported?

Thankfully, yes.

The thread is here - https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtkmm-list/2014-December/msg00002.html - and this is the official response from a primary maintainer:

> > However, the gtkmm version, Gtk::Button does not inherit from
> >     Gtk::Actionable. Therefore the functionality is not available. **There
> >     is a TODO in button.h:**
> >
> > *//TODO: Derive from (and implement) Actionable when we can break ABI.*
> >
> > What does that mean? I thought that gtk3 and gtkmm3 were kept in sync,
> >     i.e. gtkmm3-3.14 would be feature-complete regarding gkt3-3.14? Is
> >     this functionality going to be implemented (when)?
> >
> > [snip]
>
> **We can't add a base class to a C++ class without breaking ABI** - that
>   generally means causing all applications that currently use that ABI
>   to crash. **Obviously we don't want to do that.** It can be done when we
>   do a parallel install such as when we went from gtkmm-2.4 to
>   gtkmm-3.0, which did not affect currently installed applications.
>
> **You can do this in the meantime:
>   gtk_actionable_set_action_name(theButton.gobj(), "somename");**
>
> See:
>   https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-basics-gobj-and-wrap.html.en
>
> --  Murray Cumming

Note: that first argument needs to be `GTK_ACTIONABLE( theButton.gobj() )`. GLib-style objects are opaque pointers only. A C++ compiler can't implicitly convert between such forward-declared C `struct`s (even if they contain each other as 'base classes'). Besides, because here we must cast from an 'object' (`GtkButton`) to an 'interface' (`GtkActionable`), an implicit cast wouldn't work: the interface can be located anywhere within its parent object, so the address must be adjusted during the cast. The `GTK_BLAH()` macros cover this.

Anyway, I digress... gtkmm 4 can break ABI with impunity, and GTK+ 4 development has begun, so the Actionable interface is now implemented by `GtkButton`. All or most other such `TODO`s requiring ABI breaks should now be resolved, too. If you find something that was missing in gtkmm 3 and has not yet been added to 4, then please submit a bug report to get it sorted.